# Vivado: after Tools->Create-and-Package-New-IP what to do components.xml output?

Tags: xilinx, vivado

Let's suppose you have a non-axi bus RTL core of verilog or vhdl files, and add them to your vivado project, and sucessfully compile the rtl source files using synthesis and taking care cancel and not run implementation stage.

Now I try to package all the verilog or vhdl into an vivado user IP using the vivado menu:

```
Tools->Create-and-Package-new-ip
```

Packaging Options: Package your current project using the project as source for creating a new IP definition

All it does is create a directory with a copy of all by verilog or vhdl source files in a directory with a "component.xml" file.

How to even use this component.xml file???

I create a new project... there's no where to even load the "component.xml" file into vivado so i can find the IP core in the IP integrator menu when making a block design??

I want to create IP cores have them nicely wrapped in separate vivado project, and then import them into a freash new project that contains only a block design.  vivado seems to not like this flow... any ideas how to do this?

(I don't know... I just think there's something half-baked about the way this works in vivado...)

I just found out I need additional step for it to be seen in current project:

```
1. Goto Sources window
2. click Hierachy tab
3. select click IP-XACT->component.xml
4. double click IP-XACT->component.xml
5. scroll to bottom  of "Package IP" window
6. click "Re-Package IP" button
7. Now it will show up under: IP Catalog->UserIP->corename
```

Still not sure how to get this to show up in a new project.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to import an already created components.xml into a clean project:

In vivado:

```
1. File->Open-IP-XACT
2. Select components.xml
3. This will open Package IP directory
4. In this window under "Review and Package" scroll to bottom
   of Review and package window and click "Package-IP"
```

Now it will show up under: IP Catalog->UserIP->corename

One would think this would show up under the "+" button for adding "things" to your project... but no... its under File->OPEN-IP-XACT menu.